# Syntax error in Influx query to extract data from influx to csv

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to extract data from my influx DB to a csv file using the below commands from terminal. It is showing me some syntax error.

`influx \
     -host "$INFLUXDB_HOST" \
     -username "$INFLUXDB_USERNAME" \
     -password "$INFLUXDB_PASSWORD" \
     -ssl \
     -precision rfc3339 \
     -format "csv" \
     -execute "select * from "users" where "_user_id" = '2830278'" \
     -database "$INFLUXDB_DATABASE" > "usersdata".csv;`

the error I'm getting is: `error parsing query: found USERS, expected identifier at line 1, char 15`

There is something I'm missing here. can someone look at this and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This did work

`influx \
     -host "$INFLUXDB_HOST" \
     -username "$INFLUXDB_USERNAME" \
     -password "$INFLUXDB_PASSWORD" \
     -ssl \
     -precision rfc3339 \
     -format "csv" \
     -execute "select * from /"users/" where /"_user_id/" = '2830278'" \
     -database "$INFLUXDB_DATABASE" > "usersdata".csv;`